# CMake and Makefile: segmentation fault

Tags: makefile, cmake, segmentation-fault

I'm calling Makefile from CMakeLists.txt. The CMakeLists.txt compiles a main.cpp file that prints "Hello world", and calls the Makefile. The Makefile compiles a test.cpp file that prints "Test". The code is fine. I checked it when I built the test.cpp just with the Makefile.

The problem is when I'm trying to build CMakeLists.txt. The "main" output works fine but the "test" output throws an exception:

> "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Here is the Makefile code:

```
all:
g++ -shared -fPIC -o test test.cpp
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Call_Makefile_From_CMake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(FullPath "/home/orz/ClionProjects/Call_Makefile_From_CMake")

add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${FullPath}/Test/test
        COMMAND make -f test.mk
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${FullPath}/Test
        )
add_custom_target(
   extern_lib
   DEPENDS ${FullPath}/Test/test
   )

add_executable(Call_Makefile_From_CMake main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Call_Makefile_From_CMake ${FullPath}/Test/test)
add_dependencies(Call_Makefile_From_CMake extern_lib)
```

Thank's for the helpers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this problem for two days and 5 minutes after i asked for help here i solved it.

I removed the

`target_link_libraries(Call_Makefile_From_CMake ${FullPath}/Test/test)`

line and it solved the problem. Now it works just fine.